# FutureCallback never executed

Tags: java, api, asynchronous, guava, future

I'm trying to get FutureCallbacks from Guava working because I want to use it in my java api for cloudflare.

Test class:

```java
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.*;

import javax.annotation.Nullable;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Test {

    @org.junit.Test

    public static void apiUsersCode( ) {
        apiMethodThatReturnsCloudflareInfos( new FutureCallback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess( @Nullable String result ) {
                System.out.println( "WORKING" );
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure( Throwable t ) {
                System.out.println( t );
            }
        } );
    }

    public static void apiMethodThatReturnsCloudflareInfos( FutureCallback<String> usersFutureCallback ) {
        Callable<String> solution = ( ) -> {
            Thread.sleep( 1000L ); // simulate slowness of next line
            return "http output"; // this is this other method that sends a http request
        };

        // runs callable async, when done: execute usersFutureCallback
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 10 );
        ListeningExecutorService service = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator( executor );
        ListenableFuture<String> listenableFuture = service.submit( solution );
        Futures.addCallback( listenableFuture, usersFutureCallback, service );
    }
}
```

When someone uses this api simplified:

1. He calls a method and pass a FutureCallback object (usersFutureCallback)
2. This method runs another method where its output is returned in the callable
3. Done

Example Api method that is beeing executed by the user

```java
apiMethodThatReturnsCloudflareInfos( new FutureCallback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess( @Nullable String cloudflareOutput ) {
        System.out.println( "WORKING" );
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure( Throwable t ) {
        System.out.println( t );
    }
} );
```

Example api methods simplefied doing

```java
public static void apiMethodThatReturnsCloudflareInfos( FutureCallback<String> usersFutureCallback ) {
    Callable<String> solution = ( ) -> {
        Thread.sleep( 1000L ); // simulate slowness of next line
        return "http output"; // this is this other method that sends a http request
    };

    // runs callable async, when done: execute usersFutureCallback
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 10 );
    ListeningExecutorService service = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator( executor );
    ListenableFuture<String> listenableFuture = service.submit( solution );
    Futures.addCallback( listenableFuture, usersFutureCallback, service );
}
```

"WORKING" is only printed when changing and adding this lines to add the listener after the callable is done.
But that is not the solution of cause.

```java
public static void apiMethodThatReturnsCloudflareInfos( FutureCallback<String> usersFutureCallback ) {
    Callable<String> solution = ( ) -> {
        Thread.sleep( 1000L ); // simulate slowness of next line
        return "http output"; // this is this other method that sends a http request
    };

    // runs callable async, when done: execute usersFutureCallback
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 10 );
    ListeningExecutorService service = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator( executor );
    ListenableFuture<String> listenableFuture = service.submit( solution );

    // i don't want that
    try {
        Thread.sleep( 10001L );
    } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Futures.addCallback( listenableFuture, usersFutureCallback, service );
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you call `apiMethodThatReturnsCloudflareInfos`?

Comment: Its beeing called by the person who uses my api. It can be everywhere.

Comment: If you run that test and there are no further tests that take more time than `solution` and there is nothing that makes the test suite wait for `listenableFuture`, your test suite will terminate before `solution` is finished.

Comment: You are right, thanks! Never thought the test suit would do that to me! :D

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in how you are testing that method. You basically create a new thread that runs your `Callable<String> solution`, but nothing will wait for that thread to finish. Once your test method is finished, your test suite will terminate and with it the thread that is running `solution`.

In a real life scenario, where your application lives longer than `solution`, you won't encounter that problem.

To solve this, you must update your test case to not terminate prematurely. You could do this by updating the `apiUsersCode()` to set some value in `onSuccess` and `onFailure`, which you wait for after calling `apiMethodThatReturnsCloudflareInfos`.

Comment: Thanks for the improvement for testing such things better!

Comment: I removed my code because it had errors, and I don't have the time now to fix it. Anyone feel free to look at the edit history and update my answer with correct code, or post a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved!**

The problem was the test suit JUnit.
It worked when testing it in a main(String[] args) method.

...everything is correct only what should help me with the tests makes the mistake :D

```java
    @Test
    public void apiUsersCode( ) {
        apiMethodThatReturnsCloudflareInfos( new FutureCallback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess( @Nullable String result ) {
                System.out.println( "WORKING" );
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure( Throwable t ) {
                System.out.println( t );
            }
        } );

        try {
            new CountDownLatch( 1 ).await(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void apiMethodThatReturnsCloudflareInfos( FutureCallback<String> usersFutureCallback ) {
        Callable<String> solution = ( ) -> {
            Thread.sleep( 1000L ); // simulate slowness of next line
            return "http output"; // this is this other method that sends a http request
        };

        // runs callable async, when done: execute usersFutureCallback
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 10 );
        ListeningExecutorService service = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator( executor );
        ListenableFuture<String> listenableFuture = service.submit( solution );
        Futures.addCallback( listenableFuture, usersFutureCallback, service );
    }
```